# How to be able to add a character at a certain string length(Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on an input system with Tkinter. I need a new line to appear on the 23rd character, without destroying any previous text.

The user will input text well over 20 characters, which after 23 characters a line needs to be added. After the 23rd character the rest of the text should show up under that in the same Tkinter Label box. Thank you!!

```
len_user_input = len(user_input)
if len_user_input > 23:
    #i have tried this but didn't work how I needed it to but I 
     #may be using it wrong '''
     new = len_user_input[:23] + '\n' + ;en_user_input[2:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're slicing the length and not the user_input.

Please try,

```
if len_user_input > 23:
    new = user_input[:23] + '\n' + user_input[23:]
```

Comment: That worked, when I posted this I didn't notice there were as many typos as their were so I'm sorry for that. Thank you though, this worked for me. I marked it correct.